# RethinkDB Query Plan

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'd like to look at the query execution plan of a complex query written for RethinkDB. How can I open it? I already looked in other forums but I did not get a hint whether such a function exists.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't tell how to get the query plan from Python, but, to use Rethinkdb's profiler, you should use the latest version of Rethinkdb (>= 1.11)

You can then view the query plan using the Web admin interface (you'll have a new 'Query profile' tab in data explorer).

You can also enable profiling in your query using `.run(profile=True)`.

Read [Rethinkdb official blog](http://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/1.11-release) for more information about this query plan/profiling feature.